# CSS Buttons on webpage don't work only when Surface Pro is connected to external monitors?

Tags: javascript, css

So our workplace has a portal, and some drop down / function / dialogue box buttons only work if you have no external monitors connected. If you connect monitors, the buttons do nothing (video attached)

To get the buttons to work again, you have to disconnect the monitors, close the browser and re open it. I have tried in Edge, Chrome & Firefox.

I am wondering if someone here could help. Happy to post code from inspect element, but I'm just the end user so I didn't want to post the whole code here.

`<button aria-label="Insert/edit image" title="Insert/edit image" type="button" tabindex="1" class="tox-tbtn" aria-pressed="false"><span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24"><path d="M5 15.7l3.3-3.2c.3-.3.7-.3 1 0L12 15l4.1-4c.3-.4.8-.4 1 0l2 1.9V5H5v10.7zM5 18V19h3l2.8-2.9-2-2L5 17.9zm14-3l-2.5-2.4-6.4 6.5H19v-4zM4 3h16c.6 0 1 .4 1 1v16c0 .6-.4 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4c0-.6.4-1 1-1zm6 8a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></span></button>`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.